# Using JSON and jquery.field.min.js library to populate Select field

Tags: ajax, json

I don't have a black belt in javascript so bear with me, I'm trying to pick it up as I go.

So I got this sample code that works great, sends JSON data back to my index.html file and whatever I name the form field, bam, the JSON data populates it.

How the hell do you populate a SELECT field though.

This is the AJAX code that looks like it's getting it done:

```
, success: function (data){
                // this uses the "jquery.field.min.js" library to easily populate your form with the data from the server
                $("#frmMain").formHash(data);
```

So wherever I define a form field like:

```
<input type="text" name="email" value="" />
```

It gets filled in with this JSON data:

{"gender":"m","name":"User 1","email":"user_1@example.com","test":"user_test","city":"test1, test2"}

So the email field shows up as user_1@example.com That's all great but when I go:

```
 <select name="city" id="city">
</select>
```

Hoping that test1 and test 2 would show up in the dropdown, no luck. What do I need to do get this into the option of the select form.

Thanks for the help...